# is there a specific design pattern in C# to model a yield curve into the NS model?

Tags: yield-curve, pricing

I successfully managed to have a nice NS model to a yield curve I am studying using R, while I am still beginner in C# I wonder if there is a specific design pattern I should follow in order to put that modelisation into a general .NET platform which may contain later other tools for pricing and risk computations .. 
So I started gathering the math libraries I can use (interpolation, optimization algorithms, ...)
But I am still thinking about the design this all should be put on, any help please ?

Comment: If you will be expanding your library of models and will want to use them in other programs, you should create a DLL that can be imported and used as your own function library.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to do, I am using mathnet.numerics library